# How to get the final source code that will be executed in django class based views?

Tags: django, python-3.x

In django class based generic views, they have defined few functions by default. We can override some or all of them as required.
As each new cbv that we write, we will override diff functions based on the requirements.

As cbv are object oriented, understanding which piece of code will be executed is a real pain to find out as the actual source of the cbv is scattered across diff files. It would become a lot easier to understand if we could just see the final source code of the cbv that we have written. Maybe just give a call to a function and see the full source code? Just like getting sql that will be executed by a django orm query.

Does something like this exists? If not, how to write  this damn function? 
I could figure out which functions are defined on which class and the mro would also be useful and required.

How to get the source of the functions?

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this ia good page for look every method of CBV

https://ccbv.co.uk/

Comment: I am aware of that site. Yes, it gives mro info, and details of methods. But it does not give the whole source code in one place. If we overwrite few default functions, they are also not accounted for on that site.

Comment: What i want get is the actual final source code of the custom cbv that we write that would be run.

Comment: It would make debugging cbv alot easier.